# circuitikz - dcvsource scale symbol

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to scale the symbol for `dcvsource` thus I try to use this snippet code:

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/dcvsource/scale=0.8}
\draw (A8) node[circ]{} to[dcvsource, l=\(V_1\)] (A10) node[circ]{};
```

but compilator complains to it.

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key 
'/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/dcvsource/scale', to which you passed '0.8', and I
am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I also test these variants:

- {bipoles/dcvsource**s**/scale=0.8}
- {bipoles/dcvsource/.cd, scale=0.8}
- {bipoles/dcvsource**s**/.cd, scale=0.8}

In [circuitikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) manuals in chap. 4.5.8. is clearly written en example for angle, so I come to conclusion that it should work similarly. Cite:

*The size of the broken part of the DC current source is configurable by changing the value of `bipoles/dcisource/angle` (default 80); values must be between 0 (no circle at all, probably not useful) and 90 (full circle, again not useful).*

The global scale defintion:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.51,transform shape]
```

doesn't fit to my code because it touches everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dvcsource` has no `scale` parameter (where did you find it?).

This componet is in the class `sources`, so it will scale with the other sources in the circuit when you issue `\ctikzset{sources/scale=0.8}`.

If you want to keep it local, just use normal TeX scoping, with `...to[dvdsource, sources/scale=0.8]` or, better, by defining a style.

For example, using a style:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
% define a smaller dcvsource using styles
\tikzset{small dcv/.style={dcvsource,
    sources/scale=0.7}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[dcvsource] ++(2,0)
        to[small dcv] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `angle` style is different, because it's a parameter *specific* to that shape, not shared with the rest of symbols in the class.